# Cannot convert value of type 'NSLayoutConstraint' to expected argument type '[NSLayoutConstraint]'

Tags: swift

am trying to add Autolayout constraints from top to my label view using this line of code:

```
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
```

but it showing me this error:

> "Cannot convert value of type 'NSLayoutConstraint' to expected argument type '[NSLayoutConstraint]"

trying to make the title label in purple color in image which I added
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NFqC.png)
I searched it on google an see many solutions but that's about to activate the constraints withVisualFormate but am trying to do it with the above line of code

anyone plz help me out
Thanks

Comment: You have to add an **array**, even for one object `addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(....)])` or use the *singular* API

Answer (score 0):

```
addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)])
```

OR

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
```